# How to add Azure Soap endpoint in wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, azure

How to add `Azure API Soup` in `wsdl` using C#. I'm using azure API in C#

Comment: Where exactly are you facing issue, explain it with the help of code?

Comment: i am including wsdl file in solution. changes the endpoint in web.config & how pass the header like this (Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key-'...................').